# How to get acknowlegement in Execute Command(SSHLibrary)

Tags: linux, robotframework

If i give Linux command as a argument to Execute Command(robot framework keyword, for communicate with remote server), how can i verify given Linux command is run correctly or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to return the return code alongside stdout (and stderr if you require) from the "Execute Command" keyword. e.g.:

```
SSHLibrary.Open Connection    hostname    port
SSHLibrary.Login    username    password
${stdout}    ${return_code}=    SSHLibrary.Execute Command    valid_command      return_rc=True
${stdout}    ${return_code}=    SSHLibrary.Execute Command    invalid_command    return_rc=True
```

In this example the first call to execute command would return a ${return_code} value of 0 and the second a non-zero status code. So you could just perform a "Should Be Equals" or similar assertion on the return code.

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite see the keyword you mentioned. Is that part of the standard library?

A quick check yields some keywords under OperatingSystem, which has some keywords that runs a command and returns the return code.

http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/OperatingSystem.html?r=2.8.1#Run And Return Rc

This should tell you whether your command executed properly because many Linux commands are silent on success.

Comment: "Run" keyword for execute in local host, but "Execute command"(SSHLibrary) for execute in remote host. http://robotframework-sshlibrary.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-sshlibrary-0.9/doc/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command

Comment: Ah I see. Are you actually hitting the concern that you want to check the return code, in case your command doesn't have output for certain states? Maybe what you could do is to write a wrapper that runs your command, let that command output to stdout / stderr normally, and returns the return code as part of stdout. At least then you could parse the output. Another alternative would be to execute something like echo $? and make sure that should be 0 if you want the command to succeed?